# Write PHP associative array to text file line by line

Tags: php, text-files, associative-array

I have an associative array that I need to write to a text file with every element in the array on a separate line.

What I have now is the following:

```
$fh = fopen("data.txt", "w") or die("Couldn't create file");

$data_text = "";
foreach($data as $info => $input)
{ $data_text .= $info . ":" . $input . "\n"; }

fwrite($fh, $data_text) or die("Couldn't write to file.");
```

The problem here is that, instead of writing every key-value pair on a new line, I was told I am placing a long string inside the text file instead.

I tried the following:

```
foreach($data as $info => $input)
{ fwrite($fh, $info . ":" . $input) or die("Couldn't write to file."); }
```

The problem here is that is places all the data on the same line. I think I could solve this by appending '\r\n' to the end, but wouldn't that also be considered as a long string? If so, what would be a better option?

after this I also need to take the text from the file and place it back in an array. In both ways I could use explode() for this with "\n" or "\r\n" as the first argument, right? or is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: `\n` would be for Unix line endings and `\r\n` for Windows. So it depends which editor you are using. *NotePad++*, *Visual Studio Code* or equivalent might help you see better. If the format isn't important, you could use `$data_text = "<?php\n$data = " . var_export($data, true);` to save to the file. The format would be different but you could then directly include it back instead of parsing it. If you need to save it as is then you could use `preg_split()` with a regex like `/\r?\n/` so that both Unix and Windows line endings work.

Comment: open your file in binary mode. (fopen should get "wb", not "w")

Answer (score 1):

I'm use **`PHP_EOL`** for end of line. This constant return correct *'End Of Line'* symbol for actual platform.

Answer (score 1):

I played a bit with your code to do it like this:

```php
<?php

// The name of your data file.
define('DATA_FILENAME', 'data.txt');

// The line endings format you desire in your TXT file.
// PHP_EOL is dependent to the platform. This might not be your case.
define('END_OF_LINE', "\n"); // Unix = "\n", Windows = "\r\n" 

// Dummy example of data you could have inside it:
$data = [
  'age' => 50,
  'firstname' => 'James',
  'lastname' => 'Bond',
  'kill_permit' => true,
];

// Just show the content in the console.
print '$data = ' . var_export($data, true) . ';' . PHP_EOL;

// Build the content of your data file.
$data_text = '';
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $data_text .= "$key:$value" . END_OF_LINE;
}

// Save the data to the file.
file_put_contents(DATA_FILENAME, $data_text) or die('Could not write to file!');

// Read the file as an array of lines, but don't put the new line
// chars in each array item.
$data_lines = file(DATA_FILENAME, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
if ($data_lines === false) {
    die('Could not read the file!');
}

// Another variable just to show what happens when reading.
$data2 = [];
foreach ($data_lines as $data_line) {
    if (preg_match('/^(\w+):(.*)$/i', $data_line, $matches)) {
        $data2[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
    }
    else {
        fprintf(STDERR, "Could not parse line $data_line" . PHP_EOL);
    }
}

// Just show the content in the console.
print '$data2 = ' . var_export($data2, true) . ';' . PHP_EOL;
```

The console output is:

```
$data = array (
  'age' => 50,
  'firstname' => 'James',
  'lastname' => 'Bond',
  'kill_permit' => true,
);
$data2 = array (
  'age' => '50',
  'firstname' => 'James',
  'lastname' => 'Bond',
  'kill_permit' => '1',
);
```

As you see, the fact of printing to `data.txt` as is and then reading it again will change the type of the values.

This is why you might consider that in your use case.
You might have to use JSON as another format. Or you could use the `var_export()` and `include()` method to save as a PHP file instead of a TXT file. But I think that JSON might be better and safer too.

Comment: There is no need to define `END_OF_LINE` as [`PHP_EOL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol) already exists

Comment: @DarkBee Yes, I know, but the question is more "what is the format of the data.txt file?" Perhaps he is running the script on Linux and has to generate it for Windows, no?

Comment: @PatrickJanser It said to put the input from a HTML Form into an array and then write the key-value pairs to a .txt file line by line in the following format:  key:value (no space, seperated by : ). I'm working on Windows, but that is does not apply to anything in this assignment.

Comment: @Xavvey The file `data.txt` that I generate and read has the format you asked. My solution can be used as is. If it's what you wanted then I'm pleased. I just pointed out the possible problems but of course it depends on your data and if this problem matters or not for your use case.